# Adwords to BigQuery Data Transfer Service does not send conversion data from video campaigns

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

I'm using the adwords to bigquery data transfer service to send data from adwords to bigquery.
I have had hundreds of video campaigns run at my company that have generated thousands of conversions, but the every single VideoConversionStats report is blank
In the picture you can see I'm querying every single VideoConversionStats table that we have, which returns 0 results.

However if I query the VideoBasicStats tables for the sum of conversions across all accounts I get 344 (which is much lower than it should be for the accounts and dates I have in the transfers).

So one report is telling me 344 conversions, but the other is telling me 0, both are wrong but why aren't the same 344 in the conversionstats table?
How can I get a correct conversion report for my video campaigns using the transfer service?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGNax.png

Comment: Seems this issue is tracked here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/114626784

Comment: VideoBasicStats table should be fine, and you should be able to get the correct metrics after backfilling.
VideoConversionStats issue is under investigation.

Comment: Thanks Xuejian, let me know how you get on with the VideoConversionStats issue

Comment: Hi Xuejian, just wondering if there have been any developments in this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response.
1) VideoBasicStats is not an issue. You only have stats for some of the dates.
2) For VideoConversionStats,  I just replied from  [issuetracker.google.com/114626784](https://issuetracker.google.com/114626784)